# Clicking over hidden element in Cypress is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cypress

I am running into this problem without finding a good solution. I tried every post that I found in Google but without success. I am isolating the problem so I can share you the exact point. I am searching an specific product in "mercadolibre.com" and I want to sort the list from the lower price to the maximum. To do so you can enter directly [here](https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/scanner-blueetooth#D%5BA:scanner%20blueetooth%5D) and clicking over the option "Menor Precio".

[image]

Doing manually this just works fine but with Cypress I am not being able to do that. This script just runs fine but the last step seems to have no effect.

```js
// Activate intelligence
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe("Main test suite for price control", () => {
    it("search scanners and order them by ascending price", () => {
      // Web access
      cy.visitAndWait("https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/scanner-blueetooth#D[A:scanner%20blueetooth");

      // Order by ascending price
      cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .andes-list__item-first-column > .andes-list__item-text > .andes-list__item-primary').click({force: true})
    });
});;
```

Maybe Am I using a bad approach to refer the object?

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would retry menu until options become visible

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => false)

before(() => {
  cy.visit('https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/scanner-blueetooth#D%5BA:scanner%20blueetooth%5D') 
})

it('retries the menu open command', () => {

  function openMenu(attempts = 0) {
    if (attempts > 6) throw 'Failed open menu'

    return cy.get('button.andes-dropdown__trigger').click()
      .then(() => {
        const option = Cypress.$('.andes-list:visible') // is list visible
        if (!option.length) {
          openMenu(++attempts)  // try again, up to 6 attempts
        } 
      })
  } 

  openMenu().then(() => {
    cy.get('a.andes-list__item:contains(Menor precio)').click()
  })

  // Verification
  cy.contains('.ui-search-result__wrapper:nth-child(1)', '$490', {timeout:20000})
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You may have noticed the polite discussion about dismissing the popups, is it necessary or not.

I believe not, and to rely on dismissing the popups will give a flaky test.

I also think the issue is as @DizzyAl says, the event handler on the dropdown button is not attached until late in the page load.

This is what I tried, using retries to give a bit more time for page loading.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => false)

before(() => {
  cy.visit('http://mercadolibre.com.ar')
  cy.get(".nav-search-input").type("scanner bluetooth para auto{enter}");
  cy.get('.ui-search-result__wrapper')  // instead of cy.wait(3000), wait for the list
})

it('gets the dropdown menu on 1st retry', {retries: 2}, () => {

  // Don't dismiss the popups

  cy.get('button.andes-dropdown__trigger').click()
  cy.contains('a.andes-list__item', 'Menor precio').click()

  // page reload happens
  cy.contains('.ui-search-result__wrapper:nth-child(1)', '$490', {timeout:20000})
});
```

Comment: Well with this script, your first run will always fail and it will throw an error.

Comment: `The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

  > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception`

Comment: This works - I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Well, that's subjective. I wouldn't consider a solution best if I know for sure, that the first iteration results in failure.

Comment: It illustrates exactly what was said about the removing the poups. And it's the reason retries were added by Cypress.

Comment: Even if the `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => false)` for the first iteration test still fails.

Comment: `Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<a class="andes-list__item andes-list__item--height-row-medium" role="listitem" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" type="standalone">...</a>

This element <a.andes-list__item.andes-list__item--height-row-medium> is not visible because its parent <div.andes-dropdown__popover> has CSS property: display: none

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.`

Comment: You've copied the code incorrectly - it works for me.

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is the code and the test runner screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/NuOmW3z

Comment: It's not my code.

Comment: Anyways, I think this discussion is not going in a direction that can be said productive. Like you I am also here to learn as well and I don't say whatever I write is 100% accurate and is the best way. So maybe I guess let the OP decide, which solution works for them.

Comment: @DizzyAl Please refresh the page and check my comment again. I have already edited that long back.

Comment: Nope, sorry, nothing showing up. If you are testing my answer, I'd be keen to see the result - but please comment on my answer. But I cannot fault this answer (yet)!

Comment: Thank you I learned a lot about retries from this use-case.

Comment: Hello guys, this solution certainly works but when I use it in the main solution, it does not. The main difference with the rest of the solution is that I am accessing first to the main web `http://mercadolibre.com.ar` and then I search in the main search box with `cy.get(".nav-search-input").type("scanner bluetooth para auto{enter}");`. In order to get it working I had to add a `cy.wait(3000)` but we know is a lazy solution. What do you think?

Comment: Instead of `cy.wait(3000)` you can just wait for the search result list (shown above). BUT you need to do that in the `before()` or a previous `it()` because the retry must not refresh the dropdown menu button (which happens after the search list displays).

Comment: Ideally, you could raise a flag with the developers & ask if the dropdown menu click event can be attached sooner, then you have less hassle with the tests. I'm not sure if it's a problem for the user of the site, because they will just click the button a second time (like the retry does).

Comment: You may prefer @Mihi's answer because it does just retry the button click, plus it's faster  and it allows you more freedom to put all commands inside the `it()` if you wish.

Comment: Yes I think I prefer Mihi's answer. Thanks for the support anyway!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the click event is being added to the dropdown button late, and the click is failing.

See [When Can The Test Start?](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/) for an discussion.

I tried to adapt the code in the article, but couldn't get it to work.

However, adding a `cy.wait()` or a `cy.intercept()` for the last network call works.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'https://bam-cell.nr-data.net/events/**').as('events')
cy.visit('https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/scanner-blueetooth#D%5BA:scanner%20blueetooth%5D')
cy.wait('@events', {timeout: 20000})

// Page has loaded, verify the top item price
cy.contains('.ui-search-result__wrapper:nth-child(1)', '$1.385')

// Open the sort-by dropdown
cy.get('button.andes-dropdown__trigger').click()

// Choose sort-by lowest price
cy.contains('a.andes-list__item', 'Menor precio').click()

// Verify first item has different price, long timeout to wait for page re-load
cy.contains('.ui-search-result__wrapper:nth-child(1)', '$490', {timeout:20000})
```

You may be able to shorten the page load wait by picking a different network call to wait on.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things on the webpage:

1. There were two pop-ups that were displayed. Once you click both of them, everything worked as expected.
2. There are random exceptions being thrown from the webpage, so you have to tell your cypress script to ignore those, for stable tests. Having said that, this is not a good practice as you want your tests to catch exceptions like this. Also, ask your devs to look into it and fix the issue causing the exception to be thrown.

The below script worked for me without any additional timeouts.

```js
cy.visit(
  'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/scanner-blueetooth#D%5BA:scanner%20blueetooth%5D'
)
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
}) //For ignoring exceptions
cy.get('#newCookieDisclaimerButton').click() //Click Accept cookies button
cy.get('.andes-button--filled > .andes-button__content').click() //Click the pop up button
cy.get('.andes-dropdown__trigger').click() //Clicks the dropdown menu button
cy.get('.andes-list > :nth-child(2)').click() //Clicks the first option from the dropdown
```

Comment: This is wrong, the dropdown opens without having to dismiss the popups.

Comment: Probably just works because of the extra time spent doing that, but that makes it just as flaky as using a `cy.wait()`.

Comment: Where did you find `cy.wait()` in the above code? Also yes the dropdown does open without having to dismiss the pop-ups but what I noticed, the behavior is uncertain in that case.

Comment: Not what I said - your extra commands are causing the wait.

Comment: That doesn't make the code wrong. And it's always a good practice to close all pop-ups because the overlay might hide some elements.

Comment: It makes it flaky, because it's the same as doing a `cy.wait()` and potentially fail if the network slows. Like I said, the popups have nothing to do with the dropdown working - it's a red herring.

Comment: Also, there is no overlay.

Comment: First of all `cy.wait()` blindly pauses the test. And it's a bad practice. Secondly, if there is a delay in networks, we can always apply individual timeouts to elements. And still, if that doesn't work we can go for a different approach. What I noticed is that the webpage generates random exceptions when the cookie pop up and one more pop-up is not clicked. Hence I clicked it. Good to know that there is no overlay.

Comment: Well I mean if you have a better approach, be sure to answer this question. Maybe I can learn something new. I liked @Dizzy AI answer. I tried to present mine. Maybe now you can share yours.

Comment: I think the 'uncaught:exception' handler is handling the errors, not the removal of the popups. It is better to wait for complete loading of the page, as you said. The problem with timeouts on elements is you need to check something with `.should()` to make it retry, but AFIK there is no way to check the event handler is present.

Comment: If I Just give the 'uncaught:exception' and not click on the pop-ups then try to click the drop done element I am getting this error - `Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible: <a class="andes-list__item andes-list__item--height-row-medium" role="listitem" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" type="standalone">...</a>`. Yes `should('be.visible')` would be a good choice. But I run the script multiple times, and as per my understanding the above script doesn't need any additional timeouts, the default 4 seconds works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, that's the same as the OP's problem. The `.should('be.visible')` is passing, but it's the wrong check - we need to check for the event handler, as per Gleb Bahmutov's article.

Comment: I cannot see the OP using `.should('be.visible')` anywhere in the code. So I don't know where did that came from? Anyways I think we have extended the conversation thread too much now :) In my opinion, if a simple solution works, why make it unnecessarily complicated. And please by all means, if you have a more optimized way of solving the problem, please add your answer here.

Comment: LOL you just wrote it - see your previous comment **Yes should('be.visible') would be a good choice**

Comment: I was replying to this part of the conversation `Yes, that's the same as the OP's problem. The .should('be.visible') is passing, but it's the wrong check`.